# libgfortran: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found

Tags: matlab, blas

I am getting the following error when I trying to a run mex file in MATLAB:

```
??? Invalid MEX-file
'findimps3.mexa64':
/MATLAB/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf)
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

update:
I found out that "strings MATLAB/.../libgfortran.so.3 | grep GFORTRAN" output GFORTRAN_1.0. I tried to changed libgfortran inside MATLAB but it didn't work. Not I think it's better to find a suitable libblas that works with GFORTRAN_1.0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

read [this link](http://judsonsnotes.com/notes/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=659:installing-matlab-in-ubuntu-1110&catid=37:tech-notes&Itemid=59), it explains how to configure matlab on some linux systems.

here the steps that are relevant to you:

> To enable running external programs, […] fortran libraries need to be properly updated and linked. Look at the output of this command:
>
> ```
> ll "$MATLABDIR/bin/glnxa64/"
> ```
>
> It is likely that [this link] exist:
>
> ```
> libgfortran.so.3 -> libgfortran.so.3.0.0
> ```
>
> Search for [this library] on your machine:
>
> ```
> locate libgfortran.so
> ```
>
> […] Update Matlab's links to point to these newer versions:
>
> ```
> sudo ln -sf [location of libgfortran.so.3.0.0] "$MATLABDIR/bin/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3"
> ```

Comment: [this link](http://judsonsnotes.com/notes/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=659:installing-matlab-in-ubuntu-1110&catid=37:tech-notes&Itemid=59) gives Error 502. Good that you repeated the necessary steps here.
In my case, `libgfortran.so.3` is not present on my system (Fedora 30), only `libgfortran.so.1` and `libgfortran.so.5`. But I guess that should go into a new question.

Answer (score 3):

I (think I) fixed this problem by running matlab with LD_PRELOAD, like this

`LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 matlab`

Notice freetype was another library I was having a similar problem with.

Comment: Note that if you don't have permission to edit `$MATLABDIR/bin` this may be your only choice. Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the following command worked:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/libgfortran.so /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86/libgfortran.so.3
```

Matlab was complaining it couldn't find the GFORTRAN1.4 in the following location:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/libgfortran.so
```

So I linked this location to the library I had :

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86/libgfortran.so.3
```

I found the location of this library by using the locate command as given above:) Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, fixed by
$ ln -sf /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0 /opt/matlab/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3

Errors I meet when using CDSP:
csdp: /opt/matlab/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by /usr/lib64/atlas/libptf77blas.so.3)

csdp: /opt/matlab/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3: version`GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by /usr/lib64/atlas/libf77blas.so.3)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem (error usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3: version `gfortran_1.4' not found) and it was actually not hard to fix. The problem seems to be that gfortran_1.4 version of libgfortran.so.3 comes from the release gcc-4.6.2 (i.e. fortran 4.6).

What I did was downloaded gcc-4.6.2 and built, using the steps: tar -xvf gcc-4.6.2.tar.gz cd gcc-4.6.2 ./contrib/download_prerequisites cd .. mkdir objdir cd objdir $PWD/../gcc-4.6.2/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.6.2 --enable-languages=c,fortran,c++,go make make install

Then, once everything was made, I went to the directory where the new, fresh libgfortran.so.3 was sitting (in my case it was /home/testuser/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libgfortran/.libs/)

I copied this version of libgfortran.so.3, and went to the directory where my program was expecting to find libgfortran.so.3. I replaced the old one (the old libgfortran.so.3) with the new one (the one we just copied).

The problem instantly went away. I hope this helps you too!